# Unable to connect from django to mysql database

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, xampp

I have created the database on XAMPP mysql which is up and running. [image: MySQL up and running] 
The database is created,

[image: djangoproject database]

I am now trying to connect from django with the following connection parameters,

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': "djangoproject",
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': '******',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': ''
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error when executing `python3 manage.py runserver` and `python3 manage.py migrate`

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'djangoproject'")
```

I have read a solution to create the database from mysql shell using the create database statement. My question is why i am not able to connect to the database already created on XAMPP mysql.

Comment: Do you have multiple mysql instances installed on your computer? If yes, you may be connecting to the wrong one.

Comment: @shadow I don't believe I do though i did execute pip3 install mysqlclient.

Comment: try connecting with mysql client via command line first. If it works then your django should work. 

mysql -uroot –p<your_pass>  djangoproject 

If this work fine then issue with django else issue is in mysql. 

This is just clue to debug your issue and not the solution.

Comment: @sopan So i logged in mysql and used 'show databases;' The djangoproject database is not there in the list.

Comment: The databases i see when executing 'show databases;' are information_schema, mysql, performance_schema and sys.

Comment: @Ayubx Try to create it `CREATE DATABASE djangoproject` and try again.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous Yes i assume that will work but what I would like to understand in that case is the purpose of the creating the database as i did via XAMPP. Phrased differently why am i not able to connect to the database created via XAMPP. Thank you.

Comment: These all just confirm my initial theory of you connecting to a different mysql server with your python code.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the port. By default, MySQL is listening to `3306`:

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': "djangoproject",
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': '******',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '3306'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, tried that. Did not work. Fyi i just installed XAMPP and created the database there. I did not install mysql separately.